# Galerkin Method: Why Set the Residuals to Zero?

Tags: numerical-methods

I don't understand why the Galerkin method weighs the residual by the shape functions and sets it equal to zero. I'd like to know the reason why. Any intuitive explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since the exact solution $u$ satisfies $Lu = 0$ in $\Omega$, if we have a numerical solution $\tilde{u}$ such that $L \tilde{u} = R$ in $\Omega$, certainly we want $R = 0$ in $\Omega$. But practically in weighted residual method we ensure, instead of $R = 0$ in $\Omega$, a weaker condition $\int_{\Omega} W(x)R(x) \, \text{d}x = 0$ for a certain weight function $W$. The condition is weaker simply because $R = 0$ in $\Omega$ implies $\int_{\Omega} W(x)R(x) \, \text{d}x = 0$.